# Is it possible to have multiple loadChildrens in the router?

Tags: angular

I'm using the final release of angular 2 and saw a great lazy load feature with loadChildren.

A minimal example

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'crisis', loadChildren: 'app/crisis/crisis.module#CrisisModule' }
];
```

In this case, the crisis.module gets lazy loaded, but its a string, not an array. But my page could exist by multiple components in multiple modules, so I'm wondering;

*can you lazy load multiple modules without making a module specificly for this route that contains the components?*

Answer (score 0):

I just came across the same issue as you and I've found a solution. I hope it will help others. You can simply do something like this

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
         path: '',
         component: DashboardComponent,
         children: [
            {
                path: 'events',
                loadChildren: './event/event.module#EventModule'
            },
            {
                path: 'participants',
                loadChildren: './participant/participant.module#ParticipantModule'
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

And of course, in your parent component (here DashbordComponent) you will have to put a `router-outlet`.